# How to Save a button selection in NSUser Defaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

```
*
```

```js
//
    //  DetailTableViewController.m
    //  BeautifulWorld
    //
    //  Created by Mahesh on 10/27/15.
    //  Copyright © 2015 Mahesh. All rights reserved.
    //
    #import "DetailTableViewController.h"
    #import "DetailTableViewCell.h"
    #import "ContentViewController.h"
    #import "TableViewHeader.h"
    @import UIKit;
    @interface DetailTableViewController ()
    @end
    @implementation DetailTableViewController{
        NSMutableArray* selectedPlaces;
        NSDictionary* place;
        NSArray* places;
    }
    DetailTableViewCell * detailcell ;
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        selectedPlaces = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        
        selectedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        
        
        //TODO:- NSUserDefaults Attempt
        
        selectedPlaces = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)[[NSUserDefaults   standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selectedPlaces"]];
        if(selectedPlaces == nil){
            selectedPlaces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Saved to Defaults");
        
        }
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        
        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
        
        detailcell.loveImageView.highlighted = YES;
        
        self.navigationItem.title = _DetailTableModal[0];
        
    //Wonders Of The World
        //[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {
            
            //Your code goes in here
            //NSLog(@"Main Thread Code");
        
       
            if ([self.navigationItem.title isEqualToString:@"Wonders Of The World"])
            {
                
                
              NSArray*  titleArray = @[@"Pyramid at 'Chichen Itza'",
                          @"Christ the Redeemer",
                          @"Great Wall of China",
                          @"Machu Picchu",
                          @"Petra",
                          @"Taj Mahal",
                          @"Colosseum ",];
                
                Title = [titleArray mutableCopy];
                
                
               NSArray*   descriptionArray = @[@"Yucatan, Mexico",
                                @"Rio de Janeiro - RJ, Brazil",
                                @"China",
                                @"Peru",
                                @"Wadi Musa,Jordan",
                                @"Agra,Uttar Pradesh,India",
                                @"Rome,Italy",];
                
                Description = [descriptionArray mutableCopy];
                
                 NSArray*  imageArray = @[@"1ChichenItza.jpg",
                          @"2ChristtheRedeemer.jpg",
                          @"3GreatWallofChina.jpg",
                          @"4MachuPicchu.jpg",
                          @"5Petra.jpg",
                          @"6Tajmahal.jpg",
                          @"7Colosseum.jpg",];
                
                Image = [imageArray mutableCopy];
                
            }
        
        
       // }];
        
        
        if ([self.navigationItem.title isEqualToString:@"Sky Scrapers"])
        {
        
          NSArray*  titleArray = @[@"Burj Kalifa",
                  @"Eiffel Tower",
                  @"Empire State Building",
       
    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        
        [self myValue];
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
    }
    #pragma mark - Table view data source
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
    }
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        
        return Title.count;
    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        
        static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"DetailCell";
        
        detailcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        
        int row = (int)[indexPath row];
        
        detailcell.DetailTableCellTitle.text = Title[row];
        detailcell.DetailTableCellDescription.text = Description[row];
        detailcell.DetailTableCellImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:Image[row]];
        
        if([selectedItems containsObject:indexPath]){
            //high
            detailcell.loveImageView.highlighted = YES;
        }else{
            //gray
            detailcell.loveImageView.highlighted = NO;
        }
        
        // Adding Tag To The Love Button
       // detailcell.loveImageView.tag = indexPath.row;
        detailcell.favouriteButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        
        // Adding Tap Guesture To Love Button
        detailcell.loveImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    //    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(loveImageTapped:)];
    //    tapGesture1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    //    [detailcell.loveImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture1];
        
        [detailcell.favouriteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loveImageTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        
        return  detailcell;
        
    }
    #pragma mark Delete Rows With Animation
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [Image removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [Description removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [Title removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        
        [tableView endUpdates];
        NSIndexPath * rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];
        NSArray * rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
        
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
       
   
        
    }
    #pragma mark Love Button Tapped
    -(void)loveImageTapped:(UIButton*)sender {
        sender.selected = !sender.selected; //calling your method
        [self saveMyValue:sender.selected];
        
        if (sender.selected) {
            [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HeartSelectedSmall"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [selectedPlaces addObject:selectedPlaces];
        }else{
            [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Heart"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
       
    } // Your Methods Added
    // Set the value
    - (void)saveMyValue:(BOOL)myValue {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[NSNumber numberWithBool:myValue ].integerValue forKey:@"myActionKeyHere"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    } // Your Methods Added
    // Get the value
    - (NSInteger)myValue {
        NSInteger myValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"myActionKeyHere"];
        return myValue ;
    }
    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return YES;
    }
    */
    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }   
    }
    */
    /*
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    }
    */
    /*
    
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return YES;
    }
    */
    #pragma mark - Navigation To The Detail Content View.
    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
       
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
            ContentViewController * contentView = [ segue destinationViewController];
            
            NSIndexPath * myindexpath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            
            int row = (int)[myindexpath row];
            contentView.ContentModal = @[Title[row],Description[row],Image[row]];
            
        }
    }
    @end Did The Same. Can you please explain me a bit more. What to do in cell for row at index path
```

*

Comment: Have you started with reading the `NSUserDefaults` documentation? https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults

Answer (score 0):

You save it like this if its a BOOL, otherwise just change to NSInteger if you want multiple options etc:

// Set the value

```
- (void)saveMyValue:(BOOL)myValue {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[NSNumber numberWithBool:myValue ].integerValue forKey:@"myActionKeyHere"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

// Get the value

```
- (NSInteger)myValue {
    NSInteger myValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"myActionKeyHere"];
    return myValue ;
}
```

Comment: This is working 100% , something is wrong in the way you are calling from your code. If you post your code here how you call this function I can check if its correct or not.

Comment: posted the whole class

Comment: @Mahesh Your code did not provide any of what I wrote in my example. However.

You need to call my "saveMyValue"  when "loveImageTapped" is called. 

You set it like : [self saveMyValue:button.selected]; 

And in your "cellForRowAtIndexPath" you need to pass in the saved value to the correct cell button to make it selected/unselected depending on your saved value.  cell.button.selected = mysavedvalue. However, this is for 1 value only, if you have many cells you need to create a dictionary with stored values etc, and save the dictionary to nsuserdefaults instead of saving one bool value

Comment: Did the same. Struck at Cell for at indexpath. Can you please help me with that. Yes i do have lot of cells. Am new and a bit confused , please dont hesittate to help.

Answer (score 0):

@Hauzin did tell you the way with NSUserDefaults.

By the way, I have an other idea about your case.

First of all, the type of the button's selection status is BOOL type.
So we have to box the BOOL value as NSNumber value. (with [NSNumber numberWithBool:xxx])

And then, if you have a UITableView and the UITableView needs a number of button's selection status, you can save the Button selection status as a NSArray.
Then you could write a method with a NSArray type argument to create the new UITableView. (e.g: - (void)setupXXXtableViewWithButtonStatus:(NSArray *)buttonStatusArray;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save button state in `NSUserDefault` you can use following code.

```
NSUserDefaults *udefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (btn.selected) {
    [udefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"isSelected"];
}else{
    [udefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"isSelected"];
}
```

To get the state of button you can use.

```
NSUserDefaults *udefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

BOOL isButtonSelected = [udefaults boolForKey:@"isSelected"];
```

Also, don't forget to call `synchronize` on `udefaults` like this.

```
[udefaults synchronize];
```

Hope, it helps.